# Is there a way to resolve ERROR: Could not find specified Maven installation in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, maven, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, cucumber-jvm

I am running Jenkins on localhost:8080. I have just started working with pipeline jobs. I created a basic jenkinsfile in my script for running selenium with cucumber test and created a declarative pipeline job in Jenkins on macOS

My jenkinsfile looks like this:

```
pipeline {
agent any

stages {
    stage ('Compile Stage') {

        steps {
            withMaven(maven : 'maven_3_6_3') {
                sh 'mvn clean install'
            }
        }
    }

    stage ('Testing Stage') {

        steps {
            withMaven(maven : 'maven_3_6_3') {
                sh 'mvn test'
            }
        }
    }


    stage ('Cucumber Reports') {
        steps {
            cucumber buildStatus: "UNSTABLE",
                fileIncludePattern: "**/cucumber.json",
                jsonReportDirectory: 'target'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the job builds in Jenkins, I get this error:

```
 ERROR: Could not find specified Maven installation 'maven_3_6_3'.
        Finished: FAILURE
```

This is the full log:

```
Started by user unknown or anonymous
    Obtained XeDemo/jenkinsfile from git https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/myrepo/repo.git
    Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
    [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
    [Pipeline] node
    Running on Jenkins in /Users/jo/.jenkins/workspace/DeclarativePipelineDemo
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
    [Pipeline] checkout
    The recommended git tool is: git
    using credential e2105da7-be79-42ae-a46d-86a636071021
     > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     > git config remote.origin.url https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/myrepo/repo.git# timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/myrepo/repo.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
     > git --version # 'git version 2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)'
    using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
     > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/myrepo/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
     > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
    Checking out Revision f2c0bef8083d26f1cjo07197940b7d58ce4bdd3 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
     > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     > git checkout -f f2c0bef8083d26f1cjo07197940b7d58ce4bdd3 # timeout=10
    Commit message: "Reformat code"
     > git rev-list --no-walk f2c0bef8083d26f1cjo07197940b7d58ce4bdd7 # timeout=10
    The recommended git tool is: git
    using credential e2105da7-be79-42ae-a46d-86a636071021
     > git rev-parse HEAD^{commit} # timeout=10
    The recommended git tool is: git
    using credential e2105da7-be79-42ae-a46d-86a636071021
    [GitCheckoutListener] Recording commits of 'git https://myrepo@bitbucket.org/myrepo/repo.git'
    [GitCheckoutListener] Found previous build 'DeclarativePipelineDemo #19' that contains recorded Git commits
    [GitCheckoutListener] -> Starting recording of new commits since 'f2c0bef8083d26f1cjo07197940b7d58ce4bdd3’
    [GitCheckoutListener] -> Git commit decorator successfully obtained 'hudson.plugins.git.browser.BitbucketWeb@6f02a6f3' to render commit links
    [GitCheckoutListener] -> No new commits found
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] withEnv
    [Pipeline] {
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Compile Stage)
    [Pipeline] withMaven
    [withMaven] Options: []
    [withMaven] Available options: 
    [withMaven] using JDK installation provided by the build agent
    [Pipeline] // withMaven
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Testing Stage)
    Stage "Testing Stage" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (Cucumber Reports)
    Stage "Cucumber Reports" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    ERROR: Could not find specified Maven installation 'maven_3_6_3'.
    Finished: FAILURE
```

To try rectify the issue, I have provided maven, java and git paths in the global tool configuration in Jenkins settings, so I don't know why the specified maven installation still cannot be found. I am the only user on the Jenkins app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the user permission to execute the maven, say if the user is jenkins, then check whether jenkins user has correct permission to execute maven or not.

Comment: @SouravAtta, please guide me on how to do this, please? I went to users settings and there is only one user listed called 'admin' which is me

Comment: Are you using windows server ?

Comment: I am using macOS Catalina

Comment: Have you configured the Maven-Installations? This option can be found in "Managing Tools". The reference Maven (maven_3_6_3) should be configured there.

Comment: Triplem, I can't find an option called Managing Tools. There is a menu called Manage Jenkins and inside there, I went to Global Tool Configuration and provided the location where Maven is installed on localhost. I did this already before getting the described error.

Comment: make sure you read this https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/ and make sure you have all the configuration in place related to maven